# Dell inspiron XPS wireless problem

Tags: wireless, dell, connection, inspiron, xps

I installed ubuntu 10.04 LTS beside Windows XP on a different partition.
But when I first turned on Ubuntu, I saw an exclamation mark on the wireless symbol on the taskbar. When I click on that icon, I can't find any network.

My wireless driver is: Dell wireless 1370 wlan mini-PCI card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the drivers found by the `Additional Drivers` tool.

Follow these simple steps:

- Plug your computer network cable to the router and make sure you have internet via the cable;
- Open the Unity Dash and look for `Additional Drivers`. Open the application found.

[image]

- In the application there will be listed drivers for your system that are not open-source or are provided by packages not regulated by Ubuntu. Select your wireless adapter from the list and press the **Activate** button on the right bottom corner of the application.

It should look something like this (maybe these are not your exact models, have a look)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I was wondering, is there any other way to do this without an wired internet connection? I would like to add that my wireless works on the windows XP that I have installed. So could I download stuff using windows and then use it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes but then we have to know exactly which packages were downloaded to be installed (that is possible), let me know if you want that and we can add some steps so you can do it manually (its harder manually).

Comment: yes I want that because that's the only choice I have as I can't possibly manage a wired connection right now. Thanks anyways! :)